# Visibility change on hover using CSS variable

Tags: html, css, variables

I have two html elements. The second element is hidden. But when hovering on first element the second one will be visible. These are two separate elements not linked. I'm trying to do this using css variables. On hover it's not getting visible.

CSS

```
#copyright-ft
{
    position: absolute; 
    overflow: visible; 
    font-family: roboto, cus-roboto, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 70px; 
    padding-left: 25px; 
    padding-right: 22px; 
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.45); 
    border: 4px rgba(236,96,202,0.24) solid; 
    border-radius: 80px; 
    top: 14px; 
    left: 25px; 
    padding-top: 10px; 
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
#copyright-ft-details
{
    position: absolute; 
    overflow: visible; 
    font-family: roboto, cus-roboto, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 40px; 
    padding-left: 35px; 
    padding-right: 35px; 
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); 
    border: 0px rgba(236,96,202,0.24) solid; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    top: 325px; 
    left: 120px; 
    padding-top: 15px; 
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    visibility: var(--copy-vsb);
    --copy-vsb: hidden;
}
#copyright-ft:hover
{
    --copy-vsb: visible;
}
```

HTML

```
<span id="copyright-ft"> <p>&copy;</p> </span>
<div id="copyright-ft-details">
    <span> elomymelo.com </span>
</div>
```

Can I do this with css without javascript event?

Comment: This is possible without a variable, but are you set on using one?

Comment: Yeah I need to know the other method. It doesn't have to be css variable any other css method. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [General Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) `~` to target the id you want to display on hovering your other ID.

```css
#copyright-ft {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  font-family: roboto, cus-roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 22px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  border: 4px rgba(236, 96, 202, 0.24) solid;
  border-radius: 80px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#copyright-ft-details {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  font-family: roboto, cus-roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border: 0px rgba(236, 96, 202, 0.24) solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 325px;
  left: 120px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  visibility: hidden;
}

#copyright-ft:hover~#copyright-ft-details {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<span id="copyright-ft">
    <p>&copy;</p>
  </span>
<div id="copyright-ft-details">
  <span> elomymelo.com </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to a tooltip. You don't need to use a CSS variable. Here's the code:

```css
#copyright-ft {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  font-family: roboto, cus-roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 22px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  border: 4px rgba(236, 96, 202, 0.24) solid;
  border-radius: 80px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

#copyright-ft-details {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  font-family: roboto, cus-roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border: 0px rgba(236, 96, 202, 0.24) solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 325px;
  left: 120px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  visibility: hidden;
}

#copyright-ft:hover ~ #copyright-ft-details {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<span id="copyright-ft">
  <p>&copy;</p>
</span>
<div id="copyright-ft-details">
  <span> elomymelo.com </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*):

> Custom properties are scoped to the element(s) they are declared on,
> and participate in the cascade: the value of such a custom property
> is that from the declaration decided by the cascading algorithm.

So I guess you can't alter the "global" variable even if you declare it on `:root` or `body` first; `#copyright-ft:hover{--copy-vsb}` may just make a local variable with the same name (notice the [example in the MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*#example)).

CSS selectors mostly works only in descendant direction: from parent to child and from first child to last child. So if your `#copyright-ft-details` is ALWAYS a late sibling and/or child of `#copyright-ft`, you can try something like this:

```css
#copyright-ft
{
    position: absolute; 
    overflow: visible; 
    font-family: roboto, cus-roboto, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 70px; 
    padding-left: 25px; 
    padding-right: 22px; 
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.45); 
    border: 4px rgba(236,96,202,0.24) solid; 
    border-radius: 80px; 
    top: 14px; 
    left: 25px; 
    padding-top: 10px; 
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
#copyright-ft-details
{
    position: absolute; 
    overflow: visible; 
    font-family: roboto, cus-roboto, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 40px; 
    padding-left: 35px; 
    padding-right: 35px; 
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); 
    border: 0px rgba(236,96,202,0.24) solid; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    top: 325px; 
    left: 120px; 
    padding-top: 15px; 
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    visibility: hidden;
}
#copyright-ft:hover ~ #copyright-ft-details,/* late sibling */
#copyright-ft:hover #copyright-ft-details,/* child */
#copyright-ft:hover ~ * #copyright-ft-details/* late sibling and child */
{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<span id="copyright-ft"> <p>&copy;</p> </span>
<div id="copyright-ft-details">
    <span> elomymelo.com </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I was trying to do this using CSS only. It is working in my case. I had other divs that were messing with the sibling selector. But I placed them both inside a div and it's working now.